# Using CasperJS' getElementInfo in the page context

Tags: javascript, casperjs

**Data**

```
<a href="/route" data-eventid="train_card" data-eventlabel="2:10"> <strong>2:10</strong>  <h5>Bristol to London</h5> <em>Platform 1</em> </a>
```

**Code**

```
function getPlatform() {
  var types = document.querySelectorAll('.appList a');
  return Array.prototype.map.call(platforms, function(e){
      return e.innerText;
     // return e.getElementInfo('em');
     // return e.fetchText('a em');
  });
};
```

If I use innerText I get :-

```
 2:10
Bristol to London
Platform 1
```

However I only want to get 'Platform 1' from the element EM, How can I do that, I have tried using getElementInfo & FetchText - see code that I have commented out , neither works.. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
return e.innerText;
```

to

```
return e.querySelector("em").textContent;
```

This is a basic example of the [Element API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element). You cannot use `casper.getElementInfo`, because `casper` is not defined inside of the page context (inside of `casper.evaluate()`).

You need to make sure that `e.querySelector("em")` is not null.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.. Im just learning.. can you explain what you mean by your 'casper is not defined' statement. ? and  re '.. is null, I assume you mean test to ensure result has something before returning it.

Comment: `e` is a DOM element, which doesn't have a `getElementInfo` function. There is the `casper.getElementInfo` function, but that is not available in the page context. The [page context is sandboxed](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html), so you cannot use variables defined outside and it is not possible to pass complex objects into the page context.